# Checking if array value is valid number in Swift 4

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have following code which is working in Objective-C:

```
NSScanner *scanner ;
for(int i = 0; i < [expression count]; i = i + 2)
{
    scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[expression objectAtIndex:i]];
    BOOL isNumeric = [scanner scanInteger:NULL] && [scanner isAtEnd];
    if(!isNumeric)
        return false;
}
return true;
```

I need equivalent code in Swift 4. I have tried different things but couldn't work it out. The requirement is to check whether the elements of array are number or not.

Comment: What is the type of `expression`?

Answer (score 2):

To check if an object is a number (`Int` in your case), you could do two things:

1. Type check via `is` or `as?`

   - This only checks the type and not the content

     ```
     let isNumberType = "1" is Int
     print(isNumberType) //false because "1" is of type String
     ```
2. Creating an `Int` via it's initializer

   - This returns an `Int?` because it can fail so further check `!= nil`

     ```
     let something = "1"
     let isNumber = Int(something) != nil
     print(isNumber) //true because "1" can be made into an Int
     ```

---

NOTE: As per your example, you're checking only even elements, hence we will use `stride(from:to:by:)`

#### Solution #1:

Assuming you have an array of `String`s, we can use the `Int` initializer to check if the `string` element can be a number, like so:

```
func check(expression: [String]) -> Bool {
    for idx in stride(from: 0, to: expression.count, by: 2) {
        let isNumeric = Int(expression[idx]) != nil
        if isNumeric == false {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

check(expression: ["1", "A", "2", "B", "3", "C"]) //true
check(expression: ["1", "A", "2", "B", "E", "C"]) //false
```

---

#### Solution #2:

Assuming your array is of type `[Any]` and you want to type check the alternate elements to be `Int` then use `is`, like so:

```
func check(expression: [Any]) -> Bool {
    for idx in stride(from: 0, to: expression.count, by: 2) {
        let isNumeric = expression[idx] is Int
        if isNumeric == false {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

check(expression: [1, "A", 2, "B", 3, "C"])   //true
check(expression: [1, "A", 2, "B", "3", "C"]) //false
```

The thing with `[Any]` is that it's elements can't be fed directly to the `Int`'s initializer without bringing it into an acceptable type.
So in this example, for simplicity sake, we are just checking if the object is exactly of type `Int` or not.
Therefore, I doubt this one suits your requirement.

Comment: the return statement without an if conditional inside the for loop will result in an undesired early exit in the first iteration

Comment: A literal translation would use Scanner. :)

Comment: @Adeel you can use collection method allSatisfy, no need to use a regular loop `return expression.allSatisfy({Int($0) != nil})`

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, my bad. I am on the move so quickly typed it up on my mobile. Will fix this and infact improve this soon.

Comment: @staticVoidMan the question is not clear. Why would him stride it 2 at a time

Comment: @LeoDabus the `allSatisfy` will not skip alternate elements as per his `i + 2` iteration requirement. EDIT: Its in his original `for` loop

Comment: @staticVoidMan I know that's why I posted it as a comment not as an answer. **The requirement is to check whether the elements of array are number or not**

**

Comment: @rmaddy True that. Haha, defo not a *literal* translation.

Comment: @LeoDabus It's OP's logic. We don't know what's in his `expression` array. Maybe as per his logic every odd element is to be a number, even elements could be anything. I just wrote the closest simplest swift code

Comment: @Adeel Have updated the answer with alternate solution and some basic explanation

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var str = "1234456";
let scanner = Scanner(string: str);
let isNumeric = scanner.scanInt(nil) && scanner.isAtEnd
if !isNumeric {
   print("not numeric")
} else {
   print("is numeric")
}
```

Overall if you just want to check the given string is an parsable Integer, I recommend you try :

```
var expressions = ["1234456","abcd"];
for str in expressions {
    if let isNumeric = Int(str) {
        print("is numeric")
    } else {
        print("not numeric")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the int initializer? Is there a difference in the kind of string representations it can detect?

Comment: I cannot pass nil to the scanInt function

Comment: Changing scanner.scanInt(nil) to scanner.scanInt() != nil actually worked. Thanks heaps

Comment: @Alexander Good point, I personally use Int(String) , but since the question was equivalent swift code. I just put this as a translated :-), will update my answer anyways.

Comment: Not my downvote but OP is checking an array not an string. **to check whether the elements of array are number or not.**

Comment: Literal translations from Objective C *almost always* make for bad Swift code. Challenge assumptions, and guide question askers in the right directions.